# Change Theme From Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, styles, fragment, android-architecture-navigation

I have a problem where I'm not able to change the style theme. I want to make sure that every time navigates to different fragments, the app theme will change. Hope can help me solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

[image]

```
class MainKonsesiFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {


        //create ContextThemeWrapper from the original Activity Context with the custom theme
        val context = ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.AppKonsesiTheme)
        //clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
        val localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(context)

        val binding:FragmentMainKonsesiBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(localInflater,R.layout.fragment_main_konsesi,container,false)

        binding.cardInputPemantauan.setOnClickListener(
            Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_mainKonsesiFragment_to_inputPemantauanFragment)
        )
        binding.cardListKonsesi.setOnClickListener(
            Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_mainKonsesiFragment_to_listKonsesiFragment)
        )
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
 getActivity.getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.AppKonsesiTheme, true);
```

and maybe even call

```
getActivity().recreate();
```

if you have to. Thought you might want to change the theme before creating the fragment

Comment: I add tried both and still not working.theme, not change

Comment: @khoi can you try calling it right before you create the fragment? What exactly are you trying to change? the app bar color?

Comment: where should I add those two line code? inside onCreateView method? .And yes I want to change the app bar color. Already Add an image.

Comment: @khoi does your style change colorPrimary? are you sure it's a style and not a theme? Can you try calling the two lines of code in your Activity onCreate and see if that works? Works for me

Comment: If add the code at activity and it's worked. but when putting at the fragment, not work.

Comment: @khoi I only know how to do it by having it in an activity and then calling getActivity().recreate(); in a fragment. You could always try using a built-in app bar maybe that you can easily get change the color of. Besides that I'm not really sure. There might be a 21+ method for changing the app bar color at runtime I think, don't really remember

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207810/discussion-between-khoi-and-bruce).